# Multiplying 2 Arrays in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, arrays, reactjs, ecmascript-6, javascript-objects

I have 2 arrays

```
array1 = ["a","b"]
array2 = [ ["1","2","3"],["10","11","12"]]
```

The output I want is an array of objects

```
[
 {array1: a , array2: 1},
 {array1: a , array2: 2},
 {array1: a , array2: 3},

 {array1: b , array2: 10},
 {array1: b , array2: 11},
 {array1: b , array2: 12},
]
```

Is there a concise way to achieve this output instead of nested loops

Comment: can you encapsulate some of the logic in a function? Doesn't change complexity but could enhance readability.

Comment: eh, probably, but most *good* solutions will include some form of a nested loop.

Comment: Nothing wrong with nested loops for nested data…

Answer (score 2):

It seems like you just need two loops. There are many ways to do that. A concise way is to `reduce` `array1` and `map` `array2` into the result within the outer loop:

```js
let array1 = ["a","b"]
let array2 = [ ["1","2","3"],["10","11","12"]]

let res = array1.reduce((arr, array1, i) => 
  arr.concat(array2[i].map(array2 => ({array1, array2})))
, [])

console.log(res)
```

Answer (score 1):

You could reduce the arrays and get the cartesian product of the outer elements of each arrays.

```js
function getCartesian(object) {
    return Object.entries(object).reduce((r, [k, v]) => {
        var temp = [];
        r.forEach(s =>
            (Array.isArray(v) ? v : [v]).forEach(w =>
                (w && typeof w === 'object' ? getCartesian(w) : [w]).forEach(x =>
                    temp.push(Object.assign({}, s, { [k]: x }))
                )
            )
        );
        return temp;
    }, [{}]);
}

var array1 = ["a", "b"],
    array2 = [["1", "2", "3"], ["10", "11", "12"]],
    result = array1.reduce((r, a, i) =>
        r.concat(getCartesian({ array1: a, array2: array2[i] })), [])

console.log(result);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```

Comment: Thanks, But your solution gives a full Cartesian Product, I dont need that, if you see my question , i just need 6 objects in the result, while your solutions gives me 2x6 = 12, I need "a" with "1","2" and "3" whereas "b" with "10","11" and "12"

Answer (score 0):

You can just use the [map()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) method on the second array then use another map() method on the nested arrays. Finally, use the indexes to group the "nth" element from the first array with the elements from the "nth" nested array together inside an object like this:

```js
array1 = ["a","b"]
array2 = [ ["1","2","3"],["10","11","12"]]
let x = [];

array2.map((e,i) => { // call function on every element in array2 with index callback
  e.map((f,j) => { // call function on every element in the nested arrays with index callback
    let obj = {};
    obj["array1"] = array1[i];
    obj["array2"] = f;
    x.push(obj);
  });
});

console.log(x);
```

Answer (score 0):

This is a similar approach to **Marks Meyer** answer, but using a `forEach()` instead of the `reduce()`.

```js
let array1 = ["a","b", "c"];
let array2 = [["1","2","3"], ["10","11","12"]];
let res = [];

array1.forEach((x, i) =>
{
    if (array2[i])
        res.push(...array2[i].map(y => ({array1: x, array2: y})));
});

console.log(res);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `.map()` and `.flat()` to map each element of `array2` for each element of `array1` then flatten the resulting array.

```js
const array1 = ["a","b"]
const array2 = [ ["1","2","3"],["10","11","12"]]

let res = array1.map((array1, i) => array2[i].map(array2 => ({array1, array2}))).flat()

console.log(res)
```